# Perfect Squares between two numbers

Tags: c++, algorithm

Is there any fast way in C (below 1 sec) to find the number of perfect squares between two numbers.
For ex. for 1 <-> 10 we have 2 perfect squares 4 and 9. But what about between 1<->2^60 or some other bigger number.

This is slow

```
while(i*i<=n)
{
    sum+=i==((long long)(sqrt(i*i)));
    i++;
}
```

where n is lets say 2^60 and we start with i=2.

Comment: *below 1 sec* 1 second on what, a 486 or a GeForce 560?

Comment: Why, 2^30 - 1? Can you compute `sqrt` of the endpoints and find how many integer numbers are in that range?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
x = (int)sqrt(n2) - (int)sqrt(n1);
```

Comment: Just fix indexing to get my vote up: There is 1 perfect square in [9,10]

Comment: @amit: By his example (1 <-> 10 having 2), the lower end is exclusive.

Comment: @Benjamin Lindley: I guess the higher end is also exclusive (for the symmetry). Right? Then it is `x = (int)sqrt(n2-1) - (int)sqrt(n1);` It's a pity that example 1<-->10 doesn't reveal that but it seems natural.

Comment: Where did you bring this formula Benjamin?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan:  Not every formula has to be copied from somewhere else.   Its pretty obvious once you start working out the details.

Answer (score 12):

Its trivial. Assume you have two endpoints, a & b, with a < b.

1. What is the next perfect square after a? Hint, what is sqrt(a)? What would rounding up do?
2. What is the largest perfect square that does not exceed b? Hint, what is sqrt(b)? Again, how would rounding help here?

Once you know those two numbers, counting the number of perfect squares seems truly trivial.

By the way, be careful. Even the sqrt of 2^60 is a big number, although it will fit into a double. The problem is that 2^60 is too large to fit into a standard double, since it exceeds 2^53. So beware precision issues.

Answer (score 5):

Don't iterate. The equation:

```
floor(sqrt(b)) - ceil(sqrt(a)) + 1
```

gives the number of perfect squares in the interval from `a` up to `b` inclusive.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem

Answer (score 0):

```
if(n1 is a perfect square)      
    x=(int)sqrt(n2)-(int)sqrt(n1)+1;  
else   
    x=(int)sqrt(n2)-(int)sqrt(n1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Language-agnostic formula to get the number of perfect squares in range [a, b] inclusive, as long as the basic math function sqrt, ceil and floor are provided by the standard lib.

```
cnt = int(floor(sqrt(b))) - int(ceil(sqrt(a))) + 1
```

Comment: Hope It will solve issue but please add explanation of your code with it so user will get perfect understanding which he/she really wants